# Updating a table from another table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a temp table variable with a bunch of columns:

```
 Declare @GearTemp table
    (
        ItemNumber varchar(20),
        VendorNumber varchar(6),
        ItemStatus varchar(20),
        Style varchar(20),
        ItemName varchar(100),
        ItemDescription varchar(1000),
        Color varchar(50),
        [Size] varchar(50),
        ItemCost decimal(9,4),
        IsQuickShipFl bit,
        IsEmbroiderable bit,
        IsBackOrderable bit,
        LoadDate smalldatetime
    )
```

It gets filled with data from another table via an insert statement, and I want to take that data and update my Products table.  If possible, I would like to do something like this:

```
Update Products blah blah blah  all columns where itemnumbers match up
SELECT * FROM @GearTemp FT 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT P.ItemNumber FROM Products P WHERE FT.ItemNumber = P.ItemNumber)
```

Is that possible to do? If it's not, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can there be more than one record in @GearTemp for any given Product record?  What do you want to happen in that case?

Comment: Itemnumber is the primary key, so the numbers will be unique.  Is that what your asking?

Comment: ItemNumber is the primary key for Products _and_ @GearTemp?  I'm wondering if there can be multiple entries in @GearTemp for a given ItemNumber.  If so, how do you want that handled?

Comment: No, there will only be one record for for a given itemnumber.

Comment: @Karl: I'm not exactly sure why your confused.  I specified in my question that I wish to update a table called "Products".  The data is coming from a temp table variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use something like this:

```
UPDATE p SET X = gt.X, Y = gt.Y -- etc... (not sure whether your column names match up)
FROM Products p
    INNER JOIN @GearTemp gt ON p.ItemNumber = gt.ItemNumber
```

Note that this will only work if, as you stated in the comments above, there is only ever one entry in `@GearTemp` for each `ItemNumber`.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction, but the syntax should be this:  UPDATE P SET P.X = GT.X, P.Y = GT.Y FROM Products P 
INNER JOIN @GearTemp AS GT ON P.X = GT.X

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't syntax-check in SSMS before I posted.  I'll edit it accordingly.  Glad it helped you, though!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working on SQL Server 2008 you can use the MERGE statement:

```
-- Target Table

DECLARE @tgt TABLE (OrdID INT, ItemID INT, Qty INT, Price MONEY);
INSERT INTO @tgt (OrdID, ItemID, Qty, Price)
    SELECT 1, 100, 10, 10.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 101, 10, 12.00


OrdID       ItemID      Qty         Price
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------
1           100         10          10.00
1           101         10          12.00

-- Source Table 
DECLARE @src TABLE (OrdID INT, ItemID INT, Qty INT, Price MONEY);
INSERT INTO @src (OrdID, ItemID, Qty, Price)
    SELECT 1, 100, 12, 10.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 102, 10, 12.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 103, 5, 7.00


OrdID       ItemID      Qty         Price
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------
1           100         12          13.00
1           102         10          12.00
1           103         5           7.00

MERGE @tgt AS t
USING @src AS s
ON t.OrdID = s.OrdID AND t.ItemID = s.ItemID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET 
    t.Qty = s.Qty,
    t.Price = s.Price;



Content of the target table after the MERGE operation:
OrdID       ItemID      Qty         Price
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------
1           100         12          13.00
```